# Matching UITableView and UIViewController background colours

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`. I'm trying to set both backgrounds to the same colour but despite both background having identical RGB values, they end up displaying a slight mismatch - see image below.

[image]

I have tried setting the `UITableView` background colour to clear as well but this has no effect either.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?

Comment: Have you tried running it and utilizing the view debugger? Maybe you are not looking at the component you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set the background color of tableView like below

[image]

I would also recommend you to `debug` via Debug View Hierarchy in XCode to see which view has what color.

[image]

Comment: Does it make sense where to set it? (In code or in xib)

Comment: it doesn't, but there is a possibility the BG color would have been set in Section Index by mistake in XIB.